# Chrome displaying layout incorrectly after refresh, why?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I want to start out by saying that I have read another post or two on here about this problem, but neither of them actually solved my problem. I am having display issues only on a page refresh. Meaning, the page would load fine when you just visited the page, but then when you refreshed the page it would have an incorrect layout.

The solutions offered on the other threads involved an issue with using block level elements inside an anchor. I have no anchors and I have this problem.

Here is the faulty HTML:

```
<div class="job" style="background:#a13b3b;">
    <div class="jobd" style="background:#802f2f;">
        J
    </div>
    Job Name
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for it:

```
.job {
    height:24px;
    line-height:24px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    padding-right:4px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}

.jobd {
    display:block;
    height:24px;
    width:24px;
    line-height:24px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    margin-right:4px;
}
```

As I said, it works fine in IE, FF, and even Chrome, until I refresh the page in chrome. What happens is, the second word, in this case "name" gets pushed to a new line, underneath the entire div. Even inspecting the elements show that the width of the div "job" shrinks from its correct width of 192px, down to 164px. I am completely baffled by this behavior and have no idea how to remedy this.

P.S. there are also several other places on the page where almost the exact same HTML/CSS is used and it all works perfectly, but then those have a set width.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I have a global response to several of the answers and comments so I'll edit the post here:

It's a problem on multiple pages, and for other users (I can't link because it is login restricted) but I can't replicate it on other pages, which would lead me to believe it has to do with my other elements. However, if I take out everything except this part I still have the issue. I'll clear everything but these divs, reload the page, and I have the issue with all other content gone. However, if I go to the page directly, it loads with only these divs, and it loads correctly.

Also, I don't know if it is of any consequence, but I am using xhtml 1.0 as my doctype. Another thing worth noting, is that most of the content, including this part is generated with php. I can't imagine that effecting it, but it might?

Comment: How come you aren't setting a width?

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/VsEhz/ Most likely, as noted below, your browser is cached. Or, it could be oddly interacting with other content on your page. Maybe instead of showing us your "faulty" HTML, maybe your entire structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ozojur/2/edit)

```
.job {
    height:24px;
    line-height:24px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right: 4px;
    margin-right:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    white-space: nowrap;




}

.jobd {
    display:block;
    height:24px;
    width:24px;
    line-height:24px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    margin-right:4px;
}
```

Comment: It's working on jsfiddle and jsbin for me as well, seem my edit. Also, I am not setting a width because the names that appear inside the divs are of different lengths.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to have fixed it. Thanks! this has been bugging me forever.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the page is cached. Try the same thing on something like JSFiddle and see if you can replicate the problem. If so, then it has to do with the mark-up, which I don't see why it should as it's perfect.

If you can't replicate the problem, then you know something's up with your cached page.

Comment: From your edit, it might be something bigger than that. If you can't replicate the problem with the raw code, then it has to do with the PHP/XHTML and how your server throws the markup to the browser. Try asking another question on the specific PHP issues that might lead to this. I'd say it's nothing to do with the CSS

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? I'm using 27 on Mac OS X and it looks fine to me, no matter how many times I refresh. Maybe you should try clearing the cache?

[image]

Comment: I've tried clearing the cache to no avail. I'm also using 27 on Win7.